# VS 2015 What is the difference between using "Unit Test" Project instead of plain library project for tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-devops

(Rewrited after comments)

**In Visual Studio 2015, what is the difference between using specific typed "Unit Test Project" instead of "Class Library " for a test project, apart from the cool lab icon?**

For example : 
Does it triggers special behaviour of Visual Studio ?
Would it help to automate test ? 
Does it integrate better with vs-team-services ?

My question is not about the benefit of automatic testing / continous integration in general, but on the project template/feature of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The advantage of contionus testing is that the tests run without the need of manually executing them. Usually they are executed when you make a checkin on your control-version-system which you hopefully use. In that case you get notified whenever there was a checkin that breaks your code, not only when someone hits the "run tall tests"-button. In particular when more than just you develop the software there´s a great chance that any check-in produces errors.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I have summarized my question, hope it's better formulated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Unit test' `ProjectGuids` tag allows for additional menu item behaviour, such as `Add-New Item...` will show the `Tests` group with the `Test` file templates.
It can also be used for discovery by your test runner (although built-in test runner and most modern ones don't rely on that these days).

Comment: @Pac0 It depends on the test framework you're using, i guess. I find the templates quite useful and MsTest quite sufficient. For NUnit or XUnit i suppose there are template packs and other vs extensions available with similar functionality.